# Compare an image shot using camera with one in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone-5

I want to find out if there's a way to implement the certain algorithm for my iPhone and iPad app:

- The user shoots a photo using the camera interface inside my app
- The photo is then compared with one of the photos I have inside an app
- And the photo that looks most alike is displayed

How do you do that? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can do it using AVFoundation lFramework

Comment: You can check here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055739/ios-comparing-the-two-images it contains solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at AVFoundation and AVCam in Apple library .AVCam [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) demonstrates how to use the AV Foundation capture APIs for recording movies and taking still images.

and [this](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/01/using-opencv-in-objective-c-code/) tutorial tells how to use Open CV to compare images and here is  a key method you should get start with

```
- (int)difference((int)topPixel,(int)bottomPixel)
{
    return abs(topPixel-bottomPixel);
}
```

and the last part about displaying the result, i hope it must be quite easy for you..

Comment: Question is for comparing photos. now how to take photos or recording movies.

Comment: @Jennis yeah i understand , and i have done edit with an example method .. FYI im working on similar project and have used these methods to accomplish image comparison..

Comment: @Jennis if this question is just about comparison of images then its possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049535/ios-image-comparison  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055739/ios-comparing-the-two-images but i thought user also needs to know the way to capture and store image along with comparing

Answer (score 3):

I haven't implemented anything yet, but from what i know edge detection will be neccessary in some step of your solution. There is an [open source library](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) providing edge detection:

Without having taken a closer look at it, I think this library might come handy for other tasks in your desired algorithm as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this similar question:
[Algorithm for finding similar images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891/algorithm-for-finding-similar-images)

The most reliable and general approach is to use wavelet transforms (multi-scale analysis).