# simple image recognition with any api/library

Tags: image-processing, ios7, xcode5, image-recognition, image-comparison

Is it possible to do very basic image recognition to compare an image against a database of images(resource folder images or any web servers images if we have) and determine which image in the database is the best match? I don't need to do any processing of any of the images, but simply differentiate between a finite list of images.

Is it any open source code available ?

Comment: What kind of matching do you have in mind? "Best match" seems to indicate that there could be different candidates, and that the query image might not exist in the database. "Simply differentiate" however makes it sound like you expect your query image to exist *exactly* in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using OpenCV if you simply want to compare images (i.e. decide if two images are the same).

Here is a similar question on SO:

[iOS image comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049535/ios-image-comparison)

I would also go about reading a little bit about what Core Image (the iOS image library) has to offer, before going about OpenCV or other 3rd party.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As you can see in the accepted answer to the question I linked to, OpenCV is considerably slow if you try to do complex operations, but if all you need is to decide to some degree that two images are similar, it might be exactly what you need.